# Repair windows server 2008 on dell poweredge t710

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, sata

I really have a big problem. My server could not boot.  I have an IMAGE BACKUP but when I try to recover it from external storage it asks me for a driver.

I don't know which driver to use.  I have a dell poweredge t710.

Comment: `I don't know which driver to use. I have a dell poweredge t710` - You need to figure out what drive/raid controller is in the server and go to Dell's support website and download the driver for the appropriate Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

What driver you need depends on whether it's asking for a RAID driver to restore to (get that from Dell's site) or for your external storage (get that from your external storage vendor's site).

As for which one to use:  try both of them.